# proving application is secure

Tags: amazon-web-services, security

This isn't really a technical question, but say you've developed an app for commercial use. If you get questions pertaining to the security of your app from a person who isn't necessarily technically well-versed, saying that you've taken standard security measures like encryption of passwords, protection of routes, secure database connection etc. won't have much meaning to people who don't understand what these terms mean. With that in mind, is there any way to show/prove more generally that your app is secure e.g. is there a certification from AWS for example, that will show clients that your app can be trusted?

Comment: This is pretty broad but the short answer is you can never prove it 100%. You could start with hiring a company to do penetration testing of your application. They would probe the system looking for external weaknesses. What that won't do is the hypothetical - if your DB was compromised what information could the attacker get? You'd need a full security audit for something like that. So it depends on how much money you're willing to spend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a security aware client, to gain assurance that your software is reasonably secure, you should be able to present the secure development lifecycle that was in place **during development** and resulted in secure software. Because that is really the only way to gain that assurance.

A secure sdlc includes elements like developer security awareness/education to know about and be able to avoid security issues. It includes feature reviews, security architecture and code reviews during development, static scanning (sast), dynamic scanning (dast), or more recently iast, it also includes penetration testing, and in case of SaaS, also secure operations, configuration management, log management, devsecops.

You simply cannot get this level of assurance afterwards.

You can have some elements of it though.You can run a static scan, you can buy a penetration test, you can show how you deal with security issues and so on. In many cases, that's actually good enough, but be aware that really secure software is not only this.